# Valgrind: Invalid write of size 8 with a segfault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, valgrind

So I'm working on a fairly long c code to do some data analysis. When I run it, it segfaults. I couldn't see anything obvious, so I ran it through valgrind, where I get the following:

```
==7136== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7136== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7136== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7136== Command: ./exspec table.dat datafile_1
==7136== 
Reading in table...
Obtaining rates...
Loading data from file...
==7136== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x3a00e040,     0xaa00e040) (defined)
==7136== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0xaa00f040, 0xdc11a5e0) (defined)
==7136== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x3a00e028, 0xaa00e058) (noaccess)
Converting units...
Computing fractions...
Calculating LOS and particle intersections...
==7136== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0xffefffc60 -->    0xffb6c81a0
==7136==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=59996864 or greater
==7136== Invalid write of size 8
==7136==    at 0x4040DD: get_particle_intersections (los.c:105)
==7136==    by 0x403E77: los (los.c:65)
==7136==    by 0x401236: main (main.c:73)
==7136==  Address 0xffb6c8198 is on thread 1's stack
==7136== 
==7136== 
==7136== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7136==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFB6C8198
==7136==    at 0x4040DD: get_particle_intersections (los.c:105)
==7136==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7136==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7136==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7136==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7136==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7136== 
==7136== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7136==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFB6C8191
==7136==    at 0x4A256B0: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==7136==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==7136==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==7136==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==7136==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==7136==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==7136== 
==7136== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7136==     in use at exit: 840,104,888 bytes in 4 blocks
==7136==   total heap usage: 1,447 allocs, 1,443 frees, 2,720,608,224 bytes allocated
==7136== 
==7136== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7136==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7136==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7136==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7136==    still reachable: 840,104,888 bytes in 4 blocks
==7136==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7136== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7136== 
==7136== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7136== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here's the function that it says the invalid write is in (the first part of it, anyway, as it's a bit long):

```
void get_particle_intersections(void)
{
   int i;
   int j;
   int tot_overlap = 0;
   int list[ngas];
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
   float h;

       for(i = 0; i < NPIXELS; i++)
       {
          pixels[i].noverlap = 0;

          for(j = 0; j < ngas; j++)
          {
             x = (pixels[i].pos[0] - P[j].pos[0]) / CM_PER_KPC;
             y = (pixels[i].pos[1] - P[j].pos[1]) / CM_PER_KPC;
             z = (pixels[i].pos[2] - P[j].pos[2]) / CM_PER_KPC;
             h = P[j].hsml / CM_PER_KPC;

             if((pow(x, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0) + pow(z, 2.0)) <= pow(h, 2.0))
             {
                 // Do stuff
             }
             // Do more stuff
         }
         // More stuff
     }
```

Line 105 is the if(pow... line.  Both pixels and P are globals whose memory is allocated elsewhere with:

```
if(!(pixels = calloc(NPIXELS, sizeof(PIXEL))))
{
    printf("Error, couldn't allocate memory for pixels!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and:

```
if(!(P = calloc(n_gas, sizeof(DATA))))
{
    printf("Error, couldn't allocate memory for particles!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

They are declared as:

```
PIXEL *pixels;
DATA *P;
```

The pos arrays within both pixels and P are declared as:

```
float pos[3];
```

Where PIXEL and DATA are typedef structs.  The reason I'm asking is because, if the seg fault is due to the invalid write, then I don't understand the error, as nothing is being written at that line. This led me to believe that the actual error was before this line, but for whatever reason it was only flagging it at line 105.  Anyways, like I said, the code is rather long, so I haven't posted all of it, and I guess it's possible that the error is elsewhere, but since that's where the program is crashing, I just figured I would post that section. Also, this crash is occurring in the middle of the code, so there are several arrays that have been allocated but not yet freed at this point in the program.

I've looked at several of the other questions related to invalid writes on this site, and everything seems to be related to an assignment of one data type to another, or some such thing. Since valgrind was telling me the error was at the if statement, though, I figured I'd ask. Thanks, and sorry for the rather long post!

EDIT: This is the output from gdb:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later    <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./exspec...done.
(gdb) start table.dat datafile_1 
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x40111c: file src/main.c, line 33.
Starting program: ./exspec table.dat datafile_1

Temporary breakpoint 1, main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffde88) at   src/main.c:33
33     start = clock();
(gdb) b los.c:88
Breakpoint 2 at 0x403f02: file src/los.c, line 88.
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Reading in table...
Obtaining rates...
Loading data from file...
Converting units...
Computing fractions...
Calculating LOS and particle intersections...

Breakpoint 2, get_particle_intersections () at src/los.c:88
88     for(i = 0; i < NPIXELS; i++)
(gdb) n
90        pixels[i].noverlap = 0;
(gdb) 
92        for(j = 0; j < ngas; j++)
(gdb) 
99           x = (pixels[i].pos[0] - P[j].pos[0]) / CM_PER_KPC;
(gdb) 
100          y = (pixels[i].pos[1] - P[j].pos[1]) / CM_PER_KPC;
(gdb) 
101          z = (pixels[i].pos[2] - P[j].pos[2]) / CM_PER_KPC;
(gdb) 
102          h = P[j].hsml / CM_PER_KPC;
(gdb) 
105          if((pow(x, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0) + pow(z, 2.0)) <= pow(h, 2.0))
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004040dd in get_particle_intersections () at src/los.c:105
105          if((pow(x, 2.0) + pow(y, 2.0) + pow(z, 2.0)) <= pow(h, 2.0))
```

Comment: My guess is that the invalid write is caused when pushing the arguments of `pow` to the stack. Note that valgrind reports a stack pointer corruption(?) just before the invalid write.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to see exactly where the segfault is occuring? That is, debug it directly rather than indirectly via valgrind. For example, check th `x` and `y` values and other variable values att he time of the crash to see if there is anything unexpected.

Comment: Why do you have `ngas` and `n_gas` ? Do they both have the same value ?

Comment: Agree with @AlanAu. Using the debugger is the first idea that comes to my mind when an app crashes with SIGSEGV.

Comment: Try debugging with gdb, it will be more helpful here.

Comment: I see there are/have been 1447 calls to allocate memory and that 4 of those calls have not been free'd.  And those 4 allocations are a sum of ~.8 gig in size.  That is huge.   Suggest posting the whole code to one of the available web sites, were we can download/examine for the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I first tried gdb before valgrind, and it broke in the same place. I'll post the output of it in an edit. As for the amount of memory, I am allocating a huge amount of data.  The binary file that I'm reading in is about 1.5 gigs.

Comment: What are x,y,z,h values at the time of crash?

Comment: best guess: this is a stack overflow error, caused by the dynamic array `int list[ngas];` allocated on the stack.  What is the value of `ngas`?  If it is more than 1M or so, that's going to be the problem.  The crash is on the next function call when it next tries to use the stack after allocating `list`....